# basic html/css layout not working

Tags: html, css, xml

hi i'm trying to create a very simple page but i get lost somewhere.
my idea is to create something with this structure
http://i57.tinypic.com/4r49ia.jpg
very simple... each color is a div.one on top of one another. the black rectangle is the only hard part, a space for a video for youtube.

i did this code but it just get messed up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; color:white;” >

<div id="container” style=“margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;” >

 <div id="header" style="background-color:green; height:110px;width:2000px;">
 </div>

 <div id="menu" style="background-color:blue; height:70px;width:2000px;”>
  <p>text here</p>
 </div>

 <div id=“content” style="background-color:red; text-align:center; height:800px;width:2000px;”>
 # here goes youtube video #
 </div>

 <div id="footer" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px;width:2000px; ">
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

what do i do wrong? please help me.

i get the green line, then a blue line ( but with no text in it ) and the red area is totally missiong. then there's the yellow div... why?

Comment: You should really consider writing your css in an external css file. Makes it much easier to read and organize.

Comment: You have strange quotes around content. Maybe problem comes from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have to use either margin or float in layouts, second why are you using such a big pixel value

```
<div id="main" style="width:960px;margin:0px auto;">
        <div id="hdr" style="float:left;width:100%;height:130px;background:orange;">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="bdy" style="float:left;width:100%;height:500px;background:green;">
            body
        </div>
        <div id="ftr" style="float:left;width:100%;height:80px;background:#cccccc;">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: one last thing. if i copy the video from youtube ( i did the classical thing... share, copy code and paste it in my div ) i just get a white space, but never loads. why?

Comment: if i don't add the width in pixel, it won't show the div

Comment: shows, . use iframe tag which is most common in such a way

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using a mix of regular quotations -> " and the 'smart quotes' that Mac sometimes puts in (if I had to guess). See how the quotations before margin and after white; don't match

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; color:white;” >
```

Changing the 'smart quotes' back to normal quotes should fix your issue, and right clicking in whatever your editor is and turning off Substitutions/Smart Quotes should prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which editor you are using, but: '"' and this '”' aren't  same signs...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; color:white;" >

    <div id="container" style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;" >

     <div id="header" style="background-color:green; height:110px;width:2000px;">
     </div>

     <div id="menu" style="background-color:blue; height:70px;width:2000px;">
      <p>text here</p>
     </div>

     <div id="content" style="background-color:red; text-align:center; height:800px;width:2000px;">
     # here goes youtube video #
     </div>

     <div id="footer" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px;width:2000px;">
     </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This will work - you will have to fix empty space (caused by padding/margin) of p tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's may be because of "width:2000px;". You cant see it in low resolution screen. Try for example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; color:white;” >

<div id="container” style=“margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center;” >

     <div id="header" style="background-color:green; height:110px;width:200px;">
         dfdasfasd
     </div>

     <div id="menu" style="background-color:blue; height:70px;width:200px;”>
      <p>text here</p>
     </div>

 <div id=“content” style="background-color:red; text-align:center; height:800px;width:200px;”>
 # here goes youtube video #
 </div>

 <div id="footer" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px;width:200px; ">
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Happy valentine's day ^*_*^

Answer (score 0):

replace body tag with this

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; color:white;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this comes from your `"` caracters.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/vA5AV/1/)